# how to split the items of an array

Tags: javascript

With this function, I know the days of the next seven days. So my problem is, that I wanna have only the number and not the whole date.

I get this: `Thu Jul 25 2013 15:08:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)`. How can I split this that I recive only `25`?

Here the js code:

```
Date.prototype.addDays = function(days) {
   var dat = new Date(this.valueOf())
   dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + days);
   return dat;
}

function getDates(startDate, stopDate) {
  var dateArray = new Array();
  var currentDate = startDate;
  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    dateArray.push(currentDate)
    currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
  }
  return dateArray;
}

var dateArray = getDates(new Date(), (new Date()).addDays(7));

for (i = 0; i < dateArray.length; i ++ ) {
    var arrays = dateArray[i];
    console.log(arrays);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where in your code do you receive "this"? It doesn't look like a string at all, so `.getDate()` should do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to split any strings, since you can just get the day-of-month straight from the Date instances:

```
    console.log(arrays.getDate());
```

JavaScript Date instances convert to a string when you use them in certain ways, but they've got a bunch of behaviors, as you clearly know from the code you've written to manipulate them.

Answer (score 1):

Your `dateArray` is an array of `Date` objects, and in the for loop `arrays` will be the current `Date` item, so you can get the day part of each item with the [`.getDate()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) *that you are already using* in your other function:

```
console.log(arrays.getDate());
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
dateArray.push(currentDate.getDate())
```

instead in the `getDates` function, and it'll return an array of numbers instead of date objects.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have added `.getDate()` on the push event in the while :) easiest way :)

```
while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
  dateArray.push(currentDate.getDate())
  currentDate = currentDate.addDays(1);
}
```